# How to execute a another c++ program when an option is chosen?

Tags: c++

I have this code when executed it will let the user choose an option. once the user enters an option the program will be cleared and execute another program. below is the sample. at the bottom is another program of option 1

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a;
    cout<<"Please choose an option below: \n";
    cout<<"1. Area of Shapes\n";
    cout<<"2. Cost of your items\n";
    cout<<"3. Flood Control\n";
    cout<<"4. Fibonacci Numbers\n";
    cout<<"5. Addition Table\n";
    cout<<"6. Exit\n";
    cin>> a;

system("pause");
return 0;    
}
```

Here is the program for option 1:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
float circle (float a)
{
      float z;
      z = 3.141593*(a*a);
      return (z);
}
float square (float b)
{
      float y;
      y = b * b;
      return (y);
}
float rectangle (float c, float d)
{
      float x;
      x = c * d;
      return (x);
}
float triangle (float e, float f)
{
      float w;
      w = (e * f) / 2;
      return (w);
}
void exit ()
{
     cout << "THANK YOU! GOODBYE!" <<endl;
}            
int main()
{
      float n;
      float l;
      float m;
      float radius;
      float side;
      float length;
      float width;
      float base;
      float height;

      do
      {
            cout << "1 => Area of Circle" <<endl;
            cout << "2 => Area of Square" <<endl;
            cout << "3 => Area of Rectangle" <<endl;
            cout << "4 => Area of Triangle" <<endl;
            cout << "0 => Exit" <<endl;
            cout << "Please enter number of your choice: ";
            cin >> n;
            {
                if (n==0)
                {
                         exit ();
                         system("pause");
                         return 0;
                }
                else if (n==1)
                {
                     cout << "Enter radius of the circle: ";
                     cin >> radius;
                     l = circle (radius);
                     cout << "Area of the circle is: " <<l <<endl;
                }
                else if (n==2)
                {
                     cout << "Enter side of the square: ";
                     cin >> side;
                     cout << "Area of the square is: " <<square (side) <<endl;
                }
                else if (n==3)
                {
                     cout << "Enter length of the rectangle: ";
                     cin >> length;
                     cout << "Enter width of the rectangle: ";
                     cin >> width;
                     m = rectangle (length, width);
                     cout << "Area of the rectangle is: " <<m <<endl;
                }
                else if (n==4)
                {
                     cout << "Enter base of the triangle: ";
                     cin >> base;
                     cout << "Enter height of the triangle: ";
                     cin >> height;
                     cout << "Area of the triangle is: " <<triangle (base, height) <<endl;
                }
                else
                cout << "Invalid number. Please enter a valid number below" <<endl;
                }
            }
            while (n!=0);
            cout <<endl <<endl;
            system("pause");
            return 0;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? All you've told us it what you have, not what you want to accomplish.

Comment: im only a student in programming. all i need to do is when the user wants enter option 1 it will go directly to the program of that option. I don't know if all the programs will be placed in one file or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *truely* want to replace the current program with another, look to the `exec` family of system calls.

Comment: I don't know how to use it. I'm only starting in programming and only knows the basic of it. please help

Comment: Then I would argue that you probably *don't* want to replace the current program with another, as that's rarely a beginner topic.  If you really do, then it sounds like you need more help than a site like this can provide.

Comment: not exactly replacing the current program. its just that if the user will enter option 1 it will run the program for and same with option number 2 and so on

Answer (score 0):

1. Put each "program" in its own file (or not, but it's a good idea to keep them separate).
2. Rename each "program"'s `main` to something meaningful, like "areas".
3. Declare that function in a header.
4. Include that header in your "controller" program.
5. Call the corresponding "program function" from the "controller" based on the input you read.

Comment: i'm sorry but i don't know how to start my program in the main file